# Which packages/practices are relevant for writing Structured Derivations? (similar to Dijkstra's calculational style of proofs)

Tags: math-mode, packages, equations, theorems

Does anyone know of any packages that support this style of writing proofs?

[image: A non-trivial example of "Structured Derivation" syntax, taken as a screenshot from Ralph-Johan Back's paper]

The only things that I've found are: [tex-ewd](http://ctan.org/pkg/tex-ewd), a bunch of plain TeX macros on CTAN written specifically with Dijkstra in mind; and a [Windows-only version of LyX](http://www.imped.fi/wordpress/?page_id=26&lang=en) that's been extended with support with structured derivations. (It's too bad that the LyX-SD is limited to Windows, because I'd guess that writing proofs in LyX would be wonderful)

In the case that there's nothing out there and that I have to roll my own, are there any packages that are similar enough that I could learn the "right way" to go about making a Structured Derivations package for LaTeX?

And I offer a pre-emptive "thank you" :) I'll be really grateful for any help.

If you need more information to be helpful (or even if I've just piqued your interest) here are some good resources:

- the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_derivations)
- A sort of [home page](http://www.imped.fi/e-math/structured.php) for an associated project.
- A Powerpoint presentation with lots of examples. And colors! http://www.risc.jku.at/conferences/cadgme2009/Back/TeachingMathLinzShort.pdf
- The paper containing the details and formal grammar. The example that I attached to this question is a screenshot from this paper. http://www.tara.tcd.ie/bitstream/2262/41529/1/PEER_stage2_10.1007%252Fs00165-009-0136-5.pdf

Comment: You can put the additional links without the http pershaps as code by tabbing 4 spaces and one of us of the moderators will activate the links.

Comment: There's a continuation/follow-up [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60106/how-to-alternate-labels-styles-in-enumerated-lists) about implementation.

Comment: Have you found the package you were searching for? If so, I'm interested in using it! Please let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use a sequence of `itemize` and `enumerate` environment, using the `enumitem` package to help with formatting

[image]

In the code below I've used the `resume` feature provided by the `enumitem` package to help keep the numbering of the `enumerate` environment without having to hardcode any of the numbers.

I've also used the optional argument of the `\item` command, which can be used, for example

```
\item[$\Vdash$]
```

If you plan to use this a lot though, you could always make this into a `\newcommand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% global settings for enumerate environment
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=(\arabic*),leftmargin=0mm}

% itemize environment, when at nested depths 2, 3, 4
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1cm}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1cm}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, when
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item\label{item:range} $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ when $x\geq 0$, and
            \item\label{item:pos} $x_0>0$
        \end{enumerate}
    \item[$\Vdash$] $f$ is continuous at $x_0$
    \item[$\equiv$] $\{\text{definition of continuity}\}$

            $(\forall\epsilon>0\cdot \exists\delta>0\cdot\forall x\geq 0\cdot |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon)$
    \item[$\equiv$] $\{\text{choose arbitrary }\epsilon \text{generilization rule}\}$
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Show that $(\exists\delta>0\cdot\forall x\geq 0\cdot |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon)$, when
        \begin{enumerate}[resume]
            \item $\epsilon>0$
        \end{enumerate}
        \item[$\Vdash$] $\{\text{find a suitable value for } \delta\text{ witness rule}\}$
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Show that $\delta>0\wedge(\forall x\geq 0\cdot|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon)$, when
            \begin{enumerate}[resume]
                \item $\delta=?$ $\sharp$ $\delta=\epsilon\cdot\sqrt{x_0}$
            \end{enumerate}
            \item[$\Vdash$] $\{\text{show the two conjuncts separately, use generalization rule for second conjunct}\}$
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Show that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$, when
                \begin{enumerate}[resume]
                    \item\label{item:xnonneg} $x\geq 0$, and
                    \item $|x-x_0|<\delta$
                \end{enumerate}
                \item[$\Vdash$] $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$
                \item[$=$] $\{$assumption \ref{item:range}, $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ are defined by assumptions \ref{item:xnonneg} and \ref{item:range}$\}$
                \item[] $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}|$
                \item[$=$] $\{$extend with conjugate value for $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_0}$, i.e., with $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}>0$$\}$
                \item[] $\dfrac{|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_0}}$
                \item[$\leq$] $\{$make divisor smaller, $\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ $\}$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this a common use of `\Vdash` ("forces")?

Answer (score 5):

You may be interested in a package written by Leslie Lamport, [`pf2`](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/pf2.pdf), which is used to produced a [**structured proof**](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/proof.pdf) that looks pretty similar to the style used by Dijkstra. The package is just a single `.sty` file and does not seem to be hosted on CTAN, but you can find it here: http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/latex/latex.html.

The style provided by this package would look like one of these two columns below (you get the freedom to change the styles of the numbering and indentation). I think after some tweaking you may be able to achieve the desired aesthetic. Well, arguably easier than the heavy-lifting using a bunch of nested `itemize` and `enumerate`.

[image: Structured proof in <code>pf2.sty</code>]

Edit: After some googling I don't find an elegant way of creating nested lists with ease. Markdown + KaTeX (or MathJax) and LaTeX conversion thru `pandoc` may be close to that but you only get a limited set of LaTeX commands supported within the Markdown environment.

Answer (score 2):

Fokkinga posted such a package in January 2015; it's called [calculation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calculation).

It follows the approach of eqnarray somehow (so says the documentation). So fractions and big operators get cramped. Otherwise, it's nice.

Comment: The default output with [`calculation`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calculation) would have to be changed dramatically (it seems) in order to match that of the OP's post. Could you reproduce the OP's output with `calculation`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.