# How to alternate labels' styles in enumerated lists?

Tags: math-mode, lists, theorems, enumerate, enumitem

How can I alternate the display of an enumerated list's counter according to which command I've used? E.g., I want `\foo{poor Yorick!}` to look like `(9) poor Yorick!` but I want `\bar{Joelle}` to have a label like `[8] Joelle`.

[image: A screenshot of the variation I want in semi-plausible context]

### Details and Motivation

(so that we can avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

I previously asked a question about LaTeX packages for writing Structured Derivations: [Which packages/practices are relevant for writing Structured Derivations? (similar to Dijkstra's calculational style of proofs)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49416/which-packages-practices-are-relevant-for-writing-structured-derivations-simil). I'm now working small solution, inspired by the help I received.

One of the researchers behind SD simply described their proof format as a two-column list: a small one on the left for the relation symbols, and a larger one on the right for the explanations. As a result, I'm trying to implement SD as an enumerated list with `enumitem` to help with any formatting. It seems like if I can keep the definition to something as simple as an extended list environment, then nesting SDs should be natural.

Here are some pieces of what I have so far:

```
\ProvidesPackage{structured_derivations}
\RequirePackage{xparse, enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\task}{m}{
    \item[\textbullet] #1 % not numbered. i.e., also not mutating the counter
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\assumption}{s m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1} % determines if command was used with a star
        {\item[$-$]} % \assumption*{…
        {\item} % \assumption{…
                % label=(\arabic*)
    #2 % content of assumption
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\observation}{s m m}{

    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\item[$+$]}
        {\item} % label=\lbrack\arabic*\rbrack
    \{ #2 \} % justification

    \item[] #3 % actual observation
}
% TODO maybe abstract out the common structure between \observation and \assumption?

% anyway, there are more command definitions and then I probably need something like
\newlist{structured_derivation}{enumerate}{5} % picking this number pretty arbitrarily
\setlist[structured_derivation]{label={}} % because I'll be overriding it anyway?
```

Ideally, the solution to this problem will be compatible with my goal of also being able to optionally reset the counter upon nesting a derivation (to indicate that the assumptions are *not* inherited).

This is all toward the end of being able to write proofs like this:

```
% (btw, also using the exercise package)
\begin{Exercise} [number=4]
  Assume that $n,m \in \naturals$. \\
  Show: ($m$ is odd $\land$ $n$ is odd) $\implies$ $m + n$ is even.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}  
  \begin{structured_derivation}
    \task{Prove that $m + n$ is necessarily even if $m$ and $n$ are both odd.}
    \assumption*{$n \in \naturals$}
    \assumption*{$m \in \naturals$}
    \isProvedBy{assume $m$ and $n$ are odd, and then derive that $m + m$ is even to demonstrate implication}
    \begin{structured_derivation}
      \task{Prove that $m + n$ is even when:}
      \assumption{$m$ is odd}
      \assumption{$n$ is odd}
      \observation
        {definition of odd-ness}
        {$\exists{x} \in \integers \suchthat m = 2x + 1$}
      \observation
        {definition of odd-ness}
        {$\exists{y} \in \integers \suchthat n = 2y + 1$}
      % continues...
    \end{structured_derivation}
  \end{structured_derivation}
\end{Answer}
```

And I will find a genie to grant you wishes if you also know how to make the brackets unnecessary like how `\item` is:

```
\task blah
\assumption* blah
\assumption* blah
\observation blah
\begin{structured_derivation}
    \task blah
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Updated Solution:

Instead of using different macros (as in the earlier version below), I think it makes more sense to have a single macro that is flexible enough to do what you want. Here I have defined the macro `\MyItem[<left>][<right>]{<content>}`, which accepts two optional parameters:

- If none of the optional parameters are specified, the *enumerated* item is printed as `2.`
- If both optional parameters are specified, they are treated as being the left and right delimiters to be placed around the *enumerated* item.  So the enumerated item will be typeset as `<left>2<right>`.
- If only one of the optional parameters is provided then that is used as as *itemized* label and the enumeration is paused.

Here are some of the possibilities:

[image]

### Further Enhancements:

- If you have more than one of these in your document you will need to have a method to reset the counter use by the enumeration, or use a different series name.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyItem}{o o m}{%
    % If #2, second optional second parameter, is provided then
    %    use an enumerated item with #1 = left, #2 = right
    % else if the
    %    use #1, first optional parameter is provided 
    %       use #1 as the itemize label
    % else use enumerated number
    %
    % #3 = content
    %
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
            \begin{enumerate}[series=MyItem,resume=*,label={\arabic*.}]%
                \item #3%
            \end{enumerate}%
        }{%
            \begin{itemize}[label={#1}]%
                \item #3%
            \end{itemize}%
        }%
    }{%
        \begin{enumerate}[series=MyItem,resume=*,label={#1\arabic*#2}]%
            \item #3%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
    \MyItem{no parameter}
    \MyItem[(][)]{use round braces}
    \MyItem[{[}][{]}]{use square braces}
    \MyItem[$\langle$][$\rangle$]{use angle braces}
    \MyItem{no parameter - numbering continues}
    \MyItem[{[}][$\rangle$]{use mixed braces}
    \MyItem[$-$]{custom symbol}
    \MyItem[][)]{no left bracket}
    \MyItem[][]{no symbol for left and right}
    \MyItem[$\ast$][]{no symbol for right}
    \MyItem[$\circ$]{another custom symbol!}
    \MyItem{no parameter - numbering continues}
\end{document}
```

---

If I understand you correctly this should do what you want. It uses the `resume` feature available with [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem).

So, `\Foo{poor Yorick!}` uses `()` with the current `enumerate` number to provide the label. But it also accepts an optional first parameter in where you can provide your own label to use (in which case the `itemize` environment is used with the provided label so as not increment the `enumerate` counter.  Similarly for `\Bar{}` but that uses the `[]` for the enumerate label by default.

When the optional parameter is provided to either of the two macros, `\Foo` and `\Bar` behave identically.

[image]

### Further Enhancements:

- Use more meaningful names for `\Foo`, and `\Bar`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{o m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \begin{enumerate}[series=Questions,resume=*,label={(\arabic*)}]%
            \item #2%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }{%
        \begin{itemize}[label={#1}]%
            \item #2%
        \end{itemize}%
    }%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\Bar}{o m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \begin{enumerate}[series=Questions,resume=*,label={[\arabic*]}]%
            \item #2%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }{%
        \begin{itemize}[label={#1}]%
            \item #2%
        \end{itemize}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
    \Foo{poor Yorick!}
    \Foo[$+$]{poor Yorick!}
    \Bar{Joelle}
    \Bar[$-$]{Joelle}
    \Foo[$\circ$]{poor Yorick!}
    \Foo{poor Yorick!}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had started down a similar path to your solution earlier on, but then was worried that sequences of single-item lists could be some sort of LaTeX antipattern. So are they actually kosher?

Comment: If there are any spacing issues that you notice, they should be adjustable with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @user600510: I was not very happy with the earlier solution and have provided another one that uses a single macro.