# Is there a symbol for "hand-wave"?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

My friends and I like to joke about hand-waving in proofs, and we were wondering if there is a hand-waving symbol in LaTeX that we could use.

Comment: Have you already checked [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)? There are a few “handy” symbols available.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: See E.W. Dijkstra’s [paper on his notation](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html), particularly the section “The proof format”. You’d use something like “〈antecedent〉\\ → {by vigorous hand-waving}\\  〈consequent〉”.  See also <http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49416/2966> for tips on typesetting Dijkstra’s proof notation.