# Equational Reasoning for Functional Programming

Tags: programming, proof-package, literate-programming

How can I create equational reasoning proof like the ones in CS literatures:

```
  A + (B + C)
=   { Associativity }
  (A + B) + C
=   { Commutativity }
  (B + A) + C
```

I can't seem to find the right package except maybe with lhs2tex. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Should `A + (B + C)`, `(A + B) + C`, and `(B + A) + C` be typeset in text or math mode? Please advise.

Comment: Hi! Preferably in math mode, since the math symbols are frequently used.

Comment: These are also called [structured derivations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49416/14751), following Dijkstra's usage and practices, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution, using an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 &\quad A + ( B + C ) \\
=&\qquad \text{\{ Associativity \}} \\
 &\quad (A + B) + C \\
=&\qquad \text{\{ Commutativity \}} \\
 &\quad (B+A)+C 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 15):

This is almost identical to the first example of the `witharrows` package documentation. There are many ways to customize things, but it does seem to match the requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}
F&=A + (B + C) \Arrow{Associativity}\\
&=  (A + B) + C\Arrow{Commutativity}\\
&=  (B + A) + C%<-------don't put \\ here 
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image]